# Write test for views containing os.remove in django

Tags: python, django, django-testing, django-tests

I have a function based view function in django that receives an ID from a model, retrieve a file address and delete it using os.remove

```
image = Images.objects.get(id=image_id)
os.remove(image.file)
```

the image_id is valid and is a part of my fixture.

what's the best way to write a test for this view, without manually creating a file each time I'm testing the code?

Is there a way to change the behavior of os.remove function for test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It's called mocking, and there is a Python library for it: mock. Mock is available in the standard library as [`unittest.mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html?highlight=mock) for Python 3.3+, or [standalone](http://mock.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for earlier versions.

So you would do something like this:

```
from mock import patch
...
@patch('mymodel_module.os.remove')
def test_my_method(self, mocked_remove):
    call_my_model_method()
    self.assertTrue(mocked_remove.called)
```

(where `mymodel_module` is the models.py where your model is defined, and which presumably imports `os`.)